# не работает код на python(бот для instagram)

Tags: python, instagram

вот такой код для бота в инстанраме, firefox есть, вместо звезлочек стоит настоящий логин и пароль.

ошибка на второй строке

```
from instapy import InstaPy

session = InstaPy(username="*****", password="*****")
session.login()
session.like_by_tags(["bmw", "mercedes"], amount=5)
session.set_dont_like(["naked", "nsfw"])
session.set_do_follow(True, percentage=50)
```

```
InstaPy Version: 0.6.9
 ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._. 
Workspace in use: "C:/Users/chuva/InstaPy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chuva\OneDrive\Документы\yandex luceum\pytube.py", line 3, in <module>
    session = InstaPy(username="crja73", password="Qwased2003")
  File "C:\Users\chuva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\instapy\instapy.py", line 311, in __init__
    self.browser, err_msg = set_selenium_local_session(
  File "C:\Users\chuva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\instapy\browser.py", line 115, in set_selenium_local_session
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(
  File "C:\Users\chuva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\chuva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\chuva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\chuva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\chuva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities


[Finished in 7.1s]
```

Comment: Нормально бот в инстаграмм может работать через API. вам нужно получить токен. И забейте звездочками пароль и логин в логах ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка создания сессии конкретно Selenium, что означает, что селениум не может поднять сессию браузера. Это может быть в основном по 3 причинам:

1. Не скачан драйвер selenium firefox (конкретно драйвер, не сам firefox)
2. Не совпадают версии firefox в системе и версия selenium driver firefox
3. Драйвер selenium не прописан в PATH и не положен в фолдер. (иногда, чтобы селениум нашел драйвер, нужно прописать путь до него внутри проекта, хотя обычно он его ищет "рядом с собой")
   Прежде всего проверьте, все ли в порядке с драйвером:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

если код выдаст ошибку, значит проблема с браузером.

Comment: вот такая ошибка 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: @Rus значит что firefox driver не прописан в PATH, как я и сказал

Comment: https://selenium-python.com/install-geckodriver

Comment: я скачал дрвйвкр, дал ему путь, путь правильный, пробовал разными способами, но он всеп равно ругается на путь, не знаю почему

Comment: @Rus значит вы сделали что то не так, либо указали не верный путь, вот и все. следуйте инструкции дословно